# Angular2 component index count

Tags: angular, indexing, components

I have a button component that can trigger quite a lot of times in another component. Now i would like to know the index of this button component. I've been Googling around and i've not seen such thing.

Only thing i can think of is creating a service and keep a count there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'creating a service and keep a count there' is answer

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: @anshuVersatile Ye that's what i'm thinking

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer give me min

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Qr8YqYbtqDRaoF6K1NO6?p=preview

Comment: Can't make any sense of it. Where does the button trigger anything?

Comment: It's not the full button.component.ts, but basically the filter needs an unique ID to trigger an animation with the css `filter` property. Therefore i'm trying to give it an unique id with the index of the component: `id="filter-ripple-{{index}}"`.

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: In the example it'll always be filter-ripple-1 because the component get's re-initialised every time there's a new button. But i got it solved using a service. Thanks for your time anyways!